# How can a modification on a .pdf document be detected, or concealed?

Tags: pdf

The use of .pdf documents in court as evidence requires a showing that the .pdf has not been modified. How can the modification of an Acrobat .pdf Contract be detected, and/or concealed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if PDF was modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664161/how-to-check-if-pdf-was-modified)

Comment: The original PDF needs to be digitally signed (i.e. using cryptographic methods) by the PDF sender in a manner they cannot repudiate, e.g. with cryptographically strong algorithms using a private key only the sender has. If that signature can be successfully verified and if it signs the whole document, your PDF is exactly the document the PDF sender had himself when he signed it. Everything else cannot be proven, merely argued for.